# How to get update online members

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hi there im working on simple discord bot which include member counter(i have this done).
another think is to have online member counter and i have this partly done :

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
let myGuild = bot.guilds.get('629746562754412544');
let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
    console.log(myGuild.name);
    console.log(memberCount);
    let memberCountChanenels = myGuild.channels.get('631270774228910090');
     memberCountChanenels.setName('Liczba gości: ' + memberCount)
     .then(result => console.log(result))
     .catch(error => console.log(error));
});

bot.on('guildMemberAdd' ,member =>{
  let myGuild = bot.guilds.get('629746562754412544');
let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
    console.log(myGuild.name);
    console.log(memberCount);
    let memberCountChanenels = myGuild.channels.get('631270774228910090');
     memberCountChanenels.setName('Liczba gości: ' + memberCount)
     .then(result => console.log(result))
     .catch(error => console.log(error));


});

bot.on('guildMemberRemove' , member =>{
  let myGuild = bot.guilds.get('629746562754412544');
let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
    console.log(myGuild.name);
    console.log(memberCount);
    let memberCountChannels = myGuild.channels.get('631270774228910090');
     memberCountChannels.setName('Liczba gości: ' + memberCount)
     .then(result => console.log(result))
     .catch(error => console.log(error));

});
//online members
bot.on('ready' , ()=> {
  let myGuild = bot.guilds.get('629746562754412544');
  console.log(myGuild.name);
  let memberOnline = myGuild.members.filter(m =>m.presence.status === 'online' ).size;
  let memberOnlineChannels = myGuild.channels.get('631553203057590302')
  memberOnlineChannels.setName('Online: ' + memberOnline)
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

});
```

question is how to get online member update. Now i need to restart bot to get correct number of online users i know it has to do something with precenseUpdate but have no clue how to code that.
Thanks Tees

Comment: Just increment memberOnline whenever ``presenceUpdate`` goes from offline to online and decrement whenever it goes from online to offline

Comment: can you give example how to code this im pure noob

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like that

```
client.once("ready", () => {
  const myGuild = client.guilds.find(g => g.id === "629746562754412544");
  let memberOnline = myGuild.members.filter(
    m => m.presence.status !== "offline"
  ).size;

  client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (oldMember.guild === myGuild) {
      if (newMember.presence.status === "offline") {
        memberOnline--;
        [update the channel]
      } else if (oldMember.presence.status === "offline") {
        memberOnline++;
        [update the channel]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The important part being

```
if (oldMember.guild === myGuild) {
          if (newMember.presence.status === "offline") {
            memberOnline--;
            [update the channel]
          } else if (oldMember.presence.status === "offline") {
            memberOnline++;
            [update the channel]
          }
        }
```